# Spring: Updata database configuration dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

In my application, I want my users to be able to configure their db-properties the first time they launch the application. The db-properties will be stored in a property-file locally and spring will use this file for db-setup in the future.

The workflow will be something like:

1. Start application for the first time
   -> 2. display a page with a db-configuration form
   -> 3. user submits the form and the input is written to the db property-file locally
   -> 4. spring reads the db-properties from the property-file and instantiates datasource, transaction-nmanager, entitymanager-factory and so on.

So the challenge is how spring can start without any db-setup and then instantiate it dynamically without restarting the server when the form is submitted.

Any suggestions? :-)

Comment: Is this a web app? Do you want *every* user to be able to configure DB props, or just the admin when he sets up the app and uses it for the first time?

Comment: The admin when he sets up the app

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring's [Java Config](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) rather than XML, to instantiate the beans programmatically. This will allow you to read the properties file.

Comment: Sure, but I guess this solution requires that the server gets started the first time with some "dummy"-settings as the db-configuration. This will throw som ugly exceptions. The username, password, databasename and so on will be specified and saved in the property-file after the server has started. So my goal is to start spring without any db-settings and then instantiate and use the datasource, entetiymanager-factory etc without restarting the server.

Comment: I don't think it requires dummy settings. Just don't start up most of the Spring context until you've got the properties from the user.